# Why is there so much difference in the execution time of the below two codes for the given problem?

Tags: python

QUESTION:
You are given an array of n numbers and q queries. For each query you have to print the floor of the expected value(mean) of the subarray from L to R.

INPUT:

First line contains two integers N and Q denoting number of array elements and number of queries.

Next line contains N space seperated integers denoting array elements.

Next Q lines contain two integers L and R(indices of the array).

OUTPUT:

print a single integer denoting the answer.

:

1<= N ,Q,L,R <= 10^6

1<= Array elements <= 10^9

Sample Input:

```
5 3
1 2 3 4 5
1 3
2 4
2 5
```

Sample Output:

```
2 
3
3
```

CODE1:

```
n,q=map(int, input().split())

arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in range(0,q):
    s=0
    b=input().split()
    L=int(b[0])-1
    R=int(b[1])-1
    d=R-L+1
    for j in range(L,R+1):
        s=s+arr[j]
    print(s//d)
```

CODE 1 takes 8.02 sec to execute.

CODE2:

```
m, n = map(int, input().split())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
s = []
s1 = 0
for i in range(m):
    s1 += a[i]
    s.append(s1)
for i in range(n):
    x, y = map(int, input().split())
    if x == 1:
        print((s[y-1])//(y-x+1))
    else:
        print((s[y-1] - s[x-2])//(y-x+1))
```

while CODE2 takes only 3.1 sec to execute. why is that so? 
Please elaborate.

[problem link](https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/play-with-numbers-2/)

Answer (score 1):

this is because in code 1: you are calculating the mean for each value between l and r.
by doing this operation of k queries you are calculating sum each time and then getting mean. So your complexity becomes (k queries*complexity of getting sum/mean)

in code 2 :

you are saving the consecutive sum in an array O(n)

and when calculate the mean of k queries you are calling the sum value till l and r element from that  summed array, and then taking difference and calculating mean, so o(1) for each query. this is saving time for you.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity matters a lot. CODE1 is having two nested `for` loops, so it's time complexity is O(n^2), where as CODE2 is having two `for` loops, but in sequence, so the time complexity is O(n).